# Is peel and stick vinyl tile flooring really waterproof?

Tags: bathroom, flooring, vinyl-flooring

I am installing these [tiles](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Armstrong-12-in-x-12-in-Peel-and-Stick-Slate-Modular-Brown-Vinyl-Tile-Flooring-24-sq-ft-Case-25820/203591274#product_description) in a bathroom mainly used my youngsters in a bath.

When they inevitably splash water on the floor won't the seems in these tiles allow the water to pass through.

I really want to do the flooring install myself and want to give these tiles ago.

What can I do to prevent any water getting through the gaps?

Is caulking a viable alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are waterproof in that you can get the top as wet as you want.  They are not waterproof in that they will keep water off your floor, nor will said water not affect the bond to the floor.  These tiles may be able to last sitting in water but they will not keep water from getting underneath.  Your only options are really one sheet of vinyl or tile (could I guess use a membrane).

If you install these right though I would bet that 99% of the water (given you don't just let an inch of standing water sit) will never meet your subfloor.  No caulk is needed, just make sure that all of the edges are tight and clicked into place.  To keep your bathroom better suited for a kid you may want to make sure baseboard are sitting right on these and caulk between baseboard and tile.

Answer (score 1):

The tile you liked says "waterproof: no" in the specifications. I suggest plank-style vinyl flooring that clicks together without adhesive.

Comment: Planks won't keep your subfloor dry either...

Comment: even the groutable vinyl tiles say they aren't water proof - i think they need to add a water resistant category

Comment: [This one](http://www.homedepot.com/p/t/202819067) is specifically recommended for use in bathrooms and its "100% waterproof construction prevents warping, mold and mildew." The instructions do say that it is waterproof and "not a waterproofer," suggesting the floor underneath needs to be free of moisture problems.

Answer (score 0):

I used peel and stick in a kitchen bathroom makeover. I used a vinyl glue. with the tiles. They lasted through 11 grand children. The added adhesive helped protect the floor and improved adhesive nature of tiles. Getting ready to do it again.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't really answer the original question (would water leak through).

Comment: Thank you Wendy, for answering.  Your comment could be easily developed into a useful answer with a little more detail.  What kind of peel/stick tile did you use?  How long is "11 grandchildren"?  :-)  What type of subflooring (under the tile) was there and if it got wet from 11,000 baths, would it be noticeable?

Answer (score 0):

The previous owners of my house put peel and stick tiles over the old vinyl in the laundry room. Well our washer leaked a little from a loose connection, cleaned it up right away but noticed water coming from the edges of the tile when I stepped on them. Long story short, we now have to rip up the entire floor because the water is under all of them. These would be great for a kitchen but I would never put these in a bathroom or laundry room.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer: keep 'em coming!